# Why does a super admin on multi site get a rest_user_invalid_id error code when requesting user details through REST?

Tags: users, rest-api

My goal is to (completely) delete users from a multi site installation using the REST API.

Using DELETE or GET ends with a rest_user_invalid_id error code even though the user (and its id) exist.

`curl --user "superadmin:TOKEN" -X GET https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/5`

The authentification works just fine. What is even more obscure is the fact that for some random users this works.

I do not use WordFence or to my knowledge any other security plugin (and I am quite sure about this).

What's the API's problem and how do I solve? Any hints are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting users with the REST API isn't supported for multisite, as seen in [the source code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/11511cea386480fb00538c4e1f0eaea3868e43d3/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-users-controller.php#L872-L879):

```
// We don't support delete requests in multisite.
if ( is_multisite() ) {
    return new WP_Error(
        'rest_cannot_delete',
        __( 'The user cannot be deleted.' ),
        array( 'status' => 501 )
    );
}
```

For GET requests the user ID is checked against [`is_user_member_of_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_member_of_blog/) for the current site. If the user is a super admin but has not been explicitly added to that site then they will not be returned and you will receive the `rest_user_invalid_id` error.

Comment: OK. I understand. Are there any reasons this is handled this way?

Comment: @OpenHaus Theres a bit more information in the commit message for that code: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/1797ea7098c00fb3e6c49286a0ca0a805892cad7